# drizzle-orm with multiple many-to-one relations - Please specify relation name at normalizeRelation

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, drizzle

I have two tables and two relations that I have defined as follows:

```js
export const games = pgTable('games', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    player1Id: integer('player1_id'),
    player1Scores: json('player1_scores'),

    player2Id: integer('player2_id'),
    player2Scores: json('player2_scores'),

    winnerId: integer('winner_id'),
});

export const players = pgTable('players', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    email: varchar('email'),
    name: varchar('name', { length: 256 }),
});

export const playersRelations = relations(players, ({ many }) => ({
    games: many(games),
}));

export const gamesRelations = relations(games, ({ one }) => ({
    player1: one(players, { fields: [games.player1Id], references: [players.id] }),
    player2: one(players, { fields: [games.player2Id], references: [players.id] }),
    winner: one(players, { fields: [games.winnerId], references: [players.id] }),
}));
```

However, I get the error message with the gamesRelations that there are "multiple relations between 'games' and 'players'). If I remove the entry with 'player2' and 'winner' from the gamesRelation, it works. But then the information is missing.

Probably the error is relatively simple, but I have no more ideas and am grateful for any help.

Error message:

> There are multiple relations between "games" and "players". Please specify relation name at normalizeRelation

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Did you find another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This error is just telling you that it has found many relations that share a reference to players, and it won't know which field is the `winner`, `player1` or `player2` when you query your `gamesRelations`

All you have to do is give the `player1`, `player2` and `winner` relations names, as the error suggests.

The `one` function has a `relationName` property that can be passed to with the config.

```
one(
    your_table, 
    { 
      fields: [...], 
      references: [...], 
      // Optional `relation name` field used for disambiguating relations
      relationName: '...' 
    }
)
```

Make the following changes and I think this will fix your issue.

```
export const gamesRelations = relations(games, ({ one }) => ({
  player1: one(players, { fields: [games.player1Id], references: [players.id], relationName: 'game_player1' } ),
  player2: one(players, { fields: [games.player2Id], references: [players.id], relationName: 'game_player2' }),
  winner: one(players, { fields: [games.winnerId], references: [players.id], relationName:  'game_winner' }),
}));
```

This isn't mentioned in the docs but you can find the code for this in this spots in their GH repo:

RelationConfig Interface -- the type for the config you're passing into `one`:
https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/main/drizzle-orm/src/relations.ts#L290

`createOne` Function -- the `one` function you're using above:
https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/main/drizzle-orm/src/relations.ts#L384

`createTableRelationsHelpers` Function -- the `relations` callback function that returns the `one` function: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/main/drizzle-orm/src/relations.ts#L488

Comment: Hmm, this didn't quite work for me. I have a very similar situation (I think) with self-referencing "one-to-many" relations, and yet even after adding a `relationName` explicitly to each relation, I still get an error like `Error: There are multiple relations between "parentageTable" and "plants". Please specify relation name`